# Script to sort contents of multiple files in a directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Good day,I have to collect the browsing history of certain people every month, and I'm a total linux noob. I would like to firstly `sort` the websites then run a `uniq -u`. The output the program I use looks like this -

```
==================================================
URL               : http://example.com/
==================================================
==================================================
URL               : http://example.com/en
==================================================
==================================================
```

There are about 30 of these in a folder `/history` named for example `bob.txt`, `tim.txt` etc. Is it possible to make a script that sorts the content in all of the files in the directory, removes all the `=` signs, removes duplicates and saves the result in a new file for example `bob.doc`, `tim.doc`?

At the moment I'm manually running `sort bob.txt | uniq -u > bob.doc`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works, at least for the example you gave:

```
for i in *.txt; do
  sed '/=/d;s/URL *: //' "$i" |
  sort -u > "${i%%.txt}".doc
done
```

#### Explanations

- `for i in *.txt; do … done` – loop over every `.txt` file in the current directory
- `sed '/=/d;s/URL *: //'` – remove every line beginning with `=`, delete the stuff before the URL in every line
- `sort -u` – sort and output only the first of an equal run
- `> "${i%%.txt}".doc` – redirect output to e.g. `bob.doc` for an input file `bob.txt` (using [Parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal))

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much! I have only just started with Linux, hope I can help someone in the future like you helped me today. Again thanks!

Comment: @Bollie If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 3):

GNU `awk` (default in Ubuntu) -- alone:

```
awk -vFPAT='https?:[^\\s]+' 'BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"} \
            /\w+/{a[$1]} END{for(i in a) print i}' *.txt
```

- Assuming all input files end in `.txt`; if not, make necessary changes in the glob pattern `*.txt`
- Variable `FPAT` sets the field definition using Regex, we have defined portion of records starting with `http` with an optional `s` after that, followed by `:`, upto next whitespace as a field by the Regex pattern `https?:[^\\s]+'`
- `awk` only supports associative arrays which are not sorted by default (well, sorted according to an internal hash -- this is an implementation detail), we are defining the sorting order of array `a` according to the index strings using associative array `PROCINFO` with key `sorted_in` having value `@ind_str_asc` by `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"`. If you want descending ordering, use `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_desc"`
- Finally, `END{for(i in a) print i}` iterates over the elements of array `a` and prints the sorted array keys.

---

If you want to save the output to a file e.g. `out.txt`:

```
awk -vFPAT='https?:[^\\s]+' 'BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"} \
            /\w+/{a[$1]} END{for(i in a) print i}' *.txt >out.txt
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to save the output of each file being processed in a corresponding file with the `.txt` extension replaced by `.doc`, leverage `awk` variable `FILENAME` to get the filename, `sub(".txt$", ".doc", FILENAME` to do the renaming and `ENDFILE` to do the array processing at the end of each file processing:

```
awk -vFPAT='https?:[^\\s]+' 'BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"} \
           /\w+/{a[$1]} ENDFILE{sub(".txt$", ".doc", FILENAME); \
                  for(i in a) print i > FILENAME}' *.txt
```